# Django 1.7, pydoc: AppRegistryNotReady Models/Apps aren't loaded yet exception

Tags: django, python-2.7, exception, pydoc

I'm working with django python 1.7 and 2.7. I have a project ('TEJUJAGUA') with a single application ('SIGAPPY') inside. The application is executed correctly when used. My problem is that I need to generate documentation with **pydoc**.

To do this, from the shell, located in the directory where the file manage.py is, I run the command:

```
pydoc -w ./
```

which produces the next output:

```
wrote SIGAPPY.html
problem in SIGAPPY.FirstView - <class 'django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady'>: Models aren't loaded yet.
wrote SIGAPPY.admin.html
problem in SIGAPPY.forms - <class 'django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady'>: Models aren't loaded yet.
wrote SIGAPPY.models.html
wrote SIGAPPY.tests.html
problem in SIGAPPY.urls - <class 'django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady'>: Models aren't loaded yet.
wrote SIGAPPY.views.html
wrote TEJUJAGUA.html
wrote TEJUJAGUA.settings.html
problem in TEJUJAGUA.urls - <class 'django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady'>: Apps aren't loaded yet.
wrote TEJUJAGUA.wsgi.html
wrote manage.html
```

Resulting in **pydoc** generating html pages to some files only, but omitting others like FirstView.py, forms.py and others.

Any ideas on why this error might be?.

I am alert in case you need any other code segment.

Comment: Maybe you have import side effects?

Comment: What kind of import side effects for example?

Comment: For instance, things that should be wrapped in `if __name__ == '__main__'` but not. I don't use Django so I'm just guessing (import side effects are one most common reason why `pydoc` fails; I'm sure it's not the only one).

Comment: This is already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24772805/python-documentation-for-django-views-generic-with-pydoc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python documentation for django.views.generic with pydoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24772805/python-documentation-for-django-views-generic-with-pydoc)